# How to set xbindkey separately for Trackpoint, Trackpad and Mouse?

Tags: mouse, touchpad, logitech, multimedia, xbindkeys

I have configured my Logitech MX-Revolution Mouse via xbindkeys on kUbuntu 18.04. I set up the extrabuttons on the scrollwheel (left/right swipe) to play the next/previous song.

My problem is, that the mapping of the keys on my Logitech mouse is equivalent to scrolling left/right on my trackpad (finger swipe). Since my Lenovo Thinkpad has also a trackpoint with physical mouse buttons, it is also equivalent to pressing the middlemousebutton while moving the trackpoint left/right.

How do I tell xbindkeys, that it should only play next/previous song if i use the key-event on my Logitech mouse? How can I set xbindkeys separately for the different input devices?

Here is my .xbindkeysrc file:

```
######### MultimediaControl #########

# backward button => previous song       
"xte 'key XF86AudioPrev'"                
   m:0x0 + b:6                                   

# forward button => next song            
"xte 'key XF86AudioNext'"                
   m:0x0 + b:7

#################################
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: if you use `xbindkeys --key` command and when you swipe your finger on trackpad,  lets say you got the result same as when you do it with logitech mouse...i think there is no way..

Comment: When i use `xbindkeys --key` command, it is printing the same keycode: `c:171` and `c:173` for the trackpoint, trackpad and for the logitech mouse.

What does the keycode `m:0x0` mean? I thought you can specify the input device with it, but unfortunately I can't get the right mouse-code.

Comment: it is somewhat indicating its a kind of modifier key and not a regular key..you can ignore then and just specify b:6 and b:7 in `.xbindkeysrc` file. regarding the codes.. bcoz both are same.. the action will also be same.. is it ok to disable these two buttons on touchpad?

Comment: Actually I would like to keep the buttons on the touchpad and on the trackpoint. But in case there is no workaround, how do I disable the buttons on touchpad and on the trackpoint without loosing the capability to scroll a page up and down?

Comment: Please run `sudo evtest`, select your logitech mouse and press one of the buttons. Is the generated event of type `EV_KEY` or `EV_REL`?

Comment: It was EV_REL. The workaround did the trick! Is there a way to set it up without a workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a ***Workaround*** with the great tool `xinput`

In your case, you have total 3 mouse devices 2 are inbuilt and one is your External mouse.

first we need to get the Id's for these 3 devices..

1. run `xinput list`

Example Output:

```
pratap@i7-6550U:~$ xinput list
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ PixArt USB Optical Mouse                  id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad                  id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech USB Receiver Mouse               id=16   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech USB Receiver Consumer Control    id=17   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Toshiba input device                      id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Logitech USB Receiver                     id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Logitech USB Receiver System Control      id=15   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Logitech USB Receiver Consumer Control    id=18   [slave  keyboard (3)]
pratap@i7-6550U:~$
```

I have 3 devices those are Mouse Inputs

> 1. PixArt USB Optical Mouse id=10
> 2. ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad id=12
> 3. Logitech USB Receiver Mouse id=16

for Example I want to bind two commands when Logitech USB Receiver Mouse with id=16 mouse wheel up & mouse wheel down that is buttons b:4 and b:5

If my `~/.xbindkeysrc` contents are like below all the 3 devices will do same function.

```
######### MultimediaControl #########

# backward button => my Command       
"gnome-control-center"                
   m:0x0 + b:4                                   

# forward button => my Command            
"gnome-tweaks"                
   m:0x0 + b:5

#####################################
```

2. run `xmodmap -pp` and see how many buttons are available.

from `man xmodmap`

```
       -pp     This option indicates that the current  pointer  map  should  be  printed  on  the
           standard output.
```

Example Output for `xmodmap -pp`

```
pratap@i7-6550U:~$ xmodmap -pp
There are 20 pointer buttons defined.

    Physical        Button
     Button          Code
        1              1
        2              2
        3              3
        4              4
        5              5
        6              6
        7              7
        8              8
        9              9
       10             10
       11             11
       12             12
       13             13
       14             14
       15             15
       16             16
       17             17
       18             18
       19             19
       20             20

pratap@i7-6550U:~$
```

this means even though we don't have 20 number of Physical buttons we can configure the specific button to do action of other out of these 20.

3. Now modify the `~/.xbindkeysrc` file content like below.

Content:

```
######### MultimediaControl #########

# backward button => my Command       
"gnome-control-center"                
   m:0x0 + b:19                                   

# forward button => my Command            
"gnome-tweaks"                
   m:0x0 + b:20

#####################################
```

4. run `killall xbindkeys; xbindkeys`

So it is clear now that if I press b:19 and b:20, my commands will run.

now the trick is to button mapping of physical buttons of the logitech mouse with id=16  b:4 and b:5 to b:19 and b:20

from `man xinput`

```
   --set-button-map device map_button_1 [map_button_2 [...]]
           Change  the  button mapping of device. The buttons are specified in physical order
           (starting with button 1) and are mapped to the logical button provided. 0 disables
           a button. The default button mapping for a device is 1 2 3 4 5 6 etc.
```

5. run `xinput --set-button-map 16 1 2 3 19 20`

Example:

```
pratap@i7-6550U:~$ xinput --set-button-map 16 1 2 3 19 20
pratap@i7-6550U:~$
```

Done, now you can have your two commands in `~/.xbindkeysrc` run with your Logitech Mouse Wheel Up & Down while other two devices have their original functions that is scroll up & down.

This button mapping will not persist after a logout or reboot.

6. add this command `xinput --set-button-map 16 1 2 3 19 20` to run at system start up.

Please note that if you change the USB slot of logitech mouse in future, the id may vary from xinput list and this will not work. You need to get the id and change it in the startup command.

Comment: You made my day !

Comment: you too made my day bcoz Original Poster of the Question did not respond..

Comment: Thank you very much @UnKNOWn! You are a genius! Sorry, that I reply so late :/
At least I was not the only one with this kind of problem.

Comment: In case anyone wants to autostart the desired configuration, the following code did the trick:

First you need to get the mouse ID by name`ID=$(xinput list --id-only 'Logitech MX Revolution Mouse')`

Then you pass the ID to ´xinput´ and define your mapping
`xinput --set-button-map $ID 1 2 3 4 5 19 20 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17`

Just copy the code to a script and run it at system startup,

Answer (score 0):

> This button mapping will not persist after a logout or reboot.

> 6. add this command xinput --set-button-map 16 1 2 3 19 20 to run at system start up.
>    Please note that if you change the USB slot of logitech mouse in future, the id may vary from xinput list and this will not work. You need to get the id and change it in the startup command.
>
> > you can sidestep this by telling xinput the device name instead of a variable device id:
> > instead of
> > `xinput --set-button-map 16 1 2 3 19 20` rather use `xinput --set-button-map pointer:'Logitech USB Receiver Mouse' 1 2 3 19 20`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately I always get the following error:
`unable to find device 'pointer:Logitech MX Revolution Mouse'`

I used your suggested command: `xinput --set-button-map pointer:'Logitech MX Revolution Mouse' 1 2 3 19 20 `